# How can I restrict which desktop applications can send data to my server?

Tags: java, security, web, authorization, streaming

I have a java server that accepts some binary data, and distributes it to the consumers which are connected by websockets.

This data (its kind is irrelevant) should only be sent by two of my desktop apps, and not by any other app. I thought about using a password, but the user must already provide one to identify him.

Any ideas?

Comment: by applying authentication/authorization

Comment: What kind of authentication/authorization credentials could a desktop app itself have? Where would they be saved?

Comment: Someone could always look at the applications bytecode and copy the authentication rendering it useless.

Comment: @dan1st yes, but how else are you going to verify where it comes from? either the application isn't reachable for those who would do such things, or it's pointless, indeed. But, if those people have access to that application anyway, why would they have to look at the bytecode, they can use the application itself.

Comment: @dac1n it's in combination with not letting everybody have that application.

Comment: If the application authenticates itself using secret keys, you don't see it when looking at the application but you can always find those if you look at its code.

Comment: @Stultuske well my applications send commands which are sent to other users with the same application, and i "trust" them to send valid and reasonable commands, because they are generated by normal usage. Someone else that knows the url could send me bogus commands that are handwritten and break the server and other apps

Comment: @dac1n so have your application be accompanied by a certificate, or a token. just knowing the url should never be enough

Comment: Where could this token be contained? In the source code of the application?

Comment: @dac1n I guess this is not what you want to hear, but if a malicious client can break your server application the problem is on the server side. The golden rule is "never trust the client". Not even your own.

Comment: Then it appears there is no answer at all? I must not receive and send dangerous data (even though it might be propey formatted), and on the other hand I cannot trust any way to identify my application?

Comment: @dac1n yeah, pretty much. Whatever you do can be broken by a sufficiently motivated adversary. Plus, planning for failure on the server side may help you also handling bugs in your own client.